# Xamarin Studio submission 64 bit app to appstore

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, xamarin, app-store, 64-bit

Problem in xamarin Studio submission 64 bit app to appstore
I work with Xamarin Studio. I transform my app with Unified Api and changed my supported architectures to "ARMv7 + AMRv7s + ARM64".
Rebuild and it's ok but when i submission my app to appstore, i receive always:

"Missing 64-bit support - Beginning on February 1, 2015 new iOS apps submitted to the App Store must include 64-bit support and be built with the iOS 8 SDK. Beginning June 1, 2015 app updates will also need to follow the same requirements. To enable 64-bit in your project, we recommend using the default Xcode build setting of “Standard architectures” to build a single binary with both 32-bit and 64-bit code."

I enable 64-bit for AppStore configuration, what's the problem? Can help me?

Comment: You should contact Xamarin's support as this will need more details (e.g. build logs) and likely the file you submitted to Apple.

Comment: If you get some solution please feed us. Yesterday i submitted an app an was approved. Today, when i try to upload a new versión i get your problem message.

Answer (score 1):

Given your description I can only guess what could be the problem there, although I've seen quite a few similar issues with ARM64 support.

- Check whether the ARM64 architecture is enabled for Release builds (or whatever build configuration you use for submitting to the AppStore)
- Check the resulting IPA whether it contains mono binaries with the '32' and '64' suffix
- Try a fully clean build (not just clean and build, i.e. checkout your scm repository into a clean directory)

Comment: deleting bin obj hidden folders, restarting vs then rebuilding helped me

Answer (score 0):

I had to make sure the debug build was set to arm64 as well. Not sure why but this solved it for me.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a device plugged into the Mac while you're compiling the AppStore build? I've had issues with it when having a device plugged in because it wants to compile for that device only.

Comment: if you had a check "enable device specific build" might be it